# Strange behavior of the collection MeteorJS

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have collection with simple docs like `{title:"some title", routes:{first:"sport",second:"football"}}` and have some categories like

```
[{
  name: "sport",
  children: {[
     {
        name: "football",
     },
     {
        name: "basketball
     }
  ]}
},
{
  //....
}
///...
]
```

**Problem:** when I switch beetwen 2 routes like "/sport/football" and "/sport/basketball" for a 1 second I see posts from another route like here:

```
1) "/sport/football"
   (I see)

  - post1
  - post2

2) go to "/sport/basketball"
   (for <1 second I see)

  - post1
  - post2
  - post3
  - post4

3)"/sport/basketball"
  (after <1 second I see)

  - post3
  - post4


 /// Code
 Template.third_level.onCreated(function(){
        var self = this;
        self.autorun(function() {
            var second_route = Session.get("current_route").params.name_second;
            var first_route = Session.get("current_route").params.name;;
            self.subscribe('posts_levels', first_route, second_route);
        });
    });

Template.third_level.helpers({
    third_level:function(){
        return Posts.find();
    },
});

<template name="third_level">
{{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
    {{#each third_level}}
        {{> third_category}}
    {{/each}}
{{/if}}
</template>

Tracker.autorun(function() {
    FlowRouter.watchPathChange();
    var currentContext = FlowRouter.current().path;
    Session.set("current_route",{
        path: currentContext,
        params: FlowRouter.current().params
    });
});

Meteor.publish("posts_levels", function(route_one, route_two){
    check(route_one , String);
    check(route_two , String);
    return Posts.find({
        routes: { $in : [{
            first: route_one,
            second: route_two
        }]}
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works like designed

1. you local collection has items 1 and 2
2. you change your subscription, you collection has still 1 and 2
3. ddp sends you messages: { added: 3 }, { added: 4 }, { removed: 1}, { removed: 2}

**NOTE: DDP sends for each insertion / deletion / update an own message, not as a single message!**

So, instead of assuming and hoping, that you collection has only the data you need and showing the whole collection via `Collection.find()` you should perform the query on the client, so you only show what you want..

So instead of:

```
third_level:function(){
    return Posts.find();
},
```

do this

```
third_level:function(){
    // get stuff from session, like in publication
    var first = Session.get // ..
    var second = Session.get // ..

    return Posts.find({routes: { $in : [{
        first: first,
        second: second
    }]}});
},
```

this way you will see only the items you need, and the collection can update its way, without strange side effects.

Another way to solve it:
Lets say you know, that after the subscription is ready you can expose the whole collection.. ok do this:

```
third_level:function() {
    if (Template.instance().subscriptionsReady())
      return Posts.find();
},
```

this way you only return if the subscription is ready, this means for some ms you view will be empty!

Comment: looks like solution, and I know about this effect! I will try it, and give you reputation

Comment: What is the difference from `{{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}` that I have in `html`

Comment: it should behave the same way.. actually

Comment: 1st solution works fine, what for 2nd mm I'm not sure